# Cutting plane parallel to two generators

Tags: conic-sections

On the following [website](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/geometry/introduction-to-conic-section.html) definitions are given for the three non-degenerate conic sections. They are defined differently based on the ways the cutting plane is parallel to the generators. While I understand the cases of ellipse and parabola, how can the hyperbola be generated when the cutting plane is at the same time parallel to **two** generators of the cone? Can anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: Consider a plane parallel to the cutting plane and passing through the cone vertex: in the case of a hyperbola, that plane intersects the cone along two generatrices.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by this. Is there any way to illustrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a picture of what I wrote in my comment above. A plane $\alpha$ cuts a double cone along a hyperbola (blue). A plane parallel to $\alpha$ and passing through the vertex cuts the cone along two generatrices (orange).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you know what I am asking. :) I have edited my question with a picture, look at *c*. They say that the plane which creates a hyperbola is parallel to 2 generatrices. So I am not looking for a case when the plane passes through the vertex. I would like to know which are those two generatrices that the plane is parallel with.

Comment: The plane of the hyperbola IS IN FACT PARALLEL TO THE ORANGE GENERATRICES. Are you not convinced of that?

Comment: I rotated the picture, in case the different orientation confounded you.

Comment: I see it more clearly now, thanks.